# How to set set and get for Textbox control?

Tags: c#, controls

I want to get value of `TextBox` in `Form1`, to another class.

I try to make a set and get, but I can't do this, because VS shows me error about ambiguity in code.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private TextBox _textBox1;

    public Form1()
    {
        this._textBox1 = textBox1;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string _textBox1
    {
        get { return _textBox1.Text; }
        set { _textBox1.Text = value; }
    }
}
```

How to make this correct? My control is private.

Comment: You have two properties called `_textbox1` one is a string the other is a textbox.

Comment: @Scrobi one field and one property to be exactly..

Comment: What do you want? To access private `TextBox` or to access `Text` property of this `TextBox`?

Comment: Get rid of `private TextBox _textBox1;` and just use `textBox1.Text` in the string property.

Answer (score 2):

You have one field and one property in you class with the same name, change the name of the property, for instance to

```
    public string FormTextBox1
    {
        get { return _textBox1.Text; }
        set { _textBox1.Text = value; }
    }
```

as naming standard the public properties must be Pascal Case notation

[Capitalization Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `textBox1.Text` to a variable, and make a getter/setter for it.

Like this:

```
public class A : Form1
{
    // assuming it's a string. If it's not, change the type
    // for the getter method below accordingly
    private string textBoxValue;

    // at some point, you'll have to make this line below:
    textBoxValue = textBox1.Value;

    public string GetTextBoxValue()
    {
        return textBoxValue;
    }
}

public class B 
{
    A aReference = new A();

   // you can get the value you want by doing
   // aReference.GetTextBoxValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void yourFormLoadMethod()
    {
        //this instantiates a new object of your class
        nameOfYourClass newYourObject = new nameOfYourClass(//put any params you need here);

        txtNameOfYourTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Enabled", newLTDObjectBenInt, "YourTextBoxEnabled", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        txtNameOfYourTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Value", newLTDObjectBenInt, "YourTextBoxEntered", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        txtNameOfYourTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Visible", newLTDObjectBenInt, "YourTextBoxVisible", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    }

    public class nameOfYourClass
    {

        //constructor
        public nameOfYourClass(//same params here from the Load method)
        {
            //place any logic that you need here to load your class properly

            //this sets default values for Enable, Visible and the text
            //you use these fields to manipulate your field as you wish
            yourTextBoxVisible = true;
            yourTextBoxEnabled = true;
            yourTextBoxEntered = "this is the default text in my textbox";
        }

        private bool yourTextBoxEnabled;
        public bool YourTextBoxEnabled
        {
            get
            {
                return yourTextBoxEnabled;
            }
            set
            {
                yourTextBoxEnabled = value;
            }
        }
        private bool yourTextBoxVisible;
        public bool YourTextBoxVisible
        {
            get
            {
                return yourTextBoxVisible;
            }
            set
            {
                yourTextBoxVisible = value;
            }
        }
        private string yourTextBoxEntered;
        public string YourTextBoxEntered
        {
            get
            {
                return yourTextBoxEntered;
            }
            set
            {
                yourTextBoxEntered = value;
            }
        }
    }
```